# Trouble getting list of words given a list of available letters for each character (Python)

Tags: python

I have a list of words that I would like to go through and remove any that don't fit my criteria.

The criteria is a list of lists of letters that are possible for each character.

```
letters = [['l','e'],['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
words = ['lab','lad','ebf','tem','abe','dan','lce']
```

The function I have written to try and solve this is:

```
def calc_words(letters,words):
    for w in words:
        for i in range(len(letters)):
          if w in words:
            for j in letters[i]:
              if w in words:
                if j != w[i]:
                    words.remove(w)
    return words
```

The output when I run the function `calc_words(letters,words)` should be `['lad', 'ebf', 'lce']`. But, I get `['lad', 'tem', 'dan']` instead.

I can't figure out what is going on. I'm relatively new to Python, so if someone either knows what is going wrong with my function, or knows a different way to go about this, I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Why should `'abe'` be part of the expected output?

Comment: ```'abe'``` was a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Just for fun a one-liner using `itertools`: `return [word for word in words if word in [''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(*letters)]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's good to avoid using one-letter variable names and reduce nesting as much as possible. Here's an implementation of `calc_words()` that should suit your needs:

```py
letters = [['l','e'],['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
words = ['lab','lad','ebf','tem','abe','dan','lce']

def calc_words(letters, words):
    # Iterate over each word.
    # Assume that a word should be in the result
    # until we reach a letter that violates the
    # constraint set by the letters list.
    result = []
    for word in words:
        all_letters_match = True
        for index, letter in enumerate(word):
            if letter not in letters[index]:
                all_letters_match = False
                break
        if all_letters_match:
            result.append(word)

    return result

# Prints "['lad', 'ebf', 'lce']".
print(calc_words(letters, words))
```

There is a comment in the first definition that describes how it works. This is similar to your implementation, with some nesting removed and some improved naming (e.g. the `if w in words` check aren't necessary, because in each iteration of `w`, `w` takes on the value of an element from `words`). I've tried to keep this solution as close to your original code.

Comment: For optimization, `letters` should be a list of sets.

Comment: @AKX If the lists are that small, how much of a performance gain do you get by using sets as opposed to lists? Hashing still has some overhead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and tips! FWIW, some words would not match criteria on multiple iterations, so when the word was attempting to be removed, but had already been removed, an exception would be raised, and the ```if w in words``` fixed that. A ```break``` would have been a much better solution to that.

Comment: @jteske54 Agreed, and happy to help. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why my function failed?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but as a general principle, it's a bad idea to modify a list while you're iterating over it. If you want to filter elements from a list, you should create a separate list (else the memory is shifting as you're trying to remove things, which can cause problems).

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark A quick `timeit` says 44% :)

Comment: What input size are you using? I’m not doubting that there might be a difference, but on an input size of 3, benchmarking isn’t very meaningful.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Various. According to this data, set lookup is always faster even when n==3. https://gist.github.com/akx/ef07ec2ed128b003535f62eaf0b647a2

Comment: @AKX Your test misses the point. The _lookup_ is faster, you never need to check it as set() is amortised O(1) whereas list lookup is O(n). _Creating_ a set now ... that is more difficult and more memory intensive then creating a list (of unique values). You left the set creation out and only tested lookup-speed - if you have few lookups in short lists  they are actually faster then creating and using the set because creation of the set takes far longer in comparison: `python -m timeit "set(range(5))"` (259 nsec) vs. `python -m timeit "list(range(5))"` (209 nsec) is a 25% markup for sets

Comment: @PatrickArtner You're right in that the test didn't measure creation time. It does now – with that, sets become (and remain) faster in this benchmark at length=10. Anyway, I don't think I missed the point in this context: OP's code has static (amortized constant time) initialization of those inner character lists, and turning them to sets will make the rest of the code faster.

Comment: `letters = [['l','e'],['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` - are 3 lists of length < 10 - so lookup in list is faster (_for this special case_) then creating the set for lookup. For the more general case of bigger lists - you are right, sets are the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickArtner No – as my benchmark points out, set lookup is faster even for small sets. Timeit'ing the post's code with `letters = [{'l', 'e'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}]` makes it 10% faster, and the performance price paid for the single static construction of that list-of-sets is negligible.